# How frequently do Community ads change?

Tags: support, advertising

The community ads present in graduated sites get changed every now and then.

I tried refreshing the page but that didnt change the ad. So is there a time limit? Does it depend on the votes that that ad got?

Comment: They have a minimum threshold. Without knowing the site to be able to look at their community advert Q&A on meta, it is hard to say why you are seeing what you are seeing.

Comment: http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/community-promotion-ads-2015

Comment: http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/3035/community-promotion-ads-2015

Comment: Note the text "There is a minimum score threshold an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be shown on the main site." - bio only has one at 9 (and one at 3 and bunch even lower).  Chemistry has a whole range of them greater than 6.

Comment: On Bio, I see Area51 proposals. And the 9 one doesn't get displayed (atleast right now).

Comment: Area 51 are a different mechanism all together. They rotate along with hot network questions, area 51 proposals that have some portion of the proposal followers and committers active on the site.  The community advertisements from the question that are rotated in are all [listed on the stats page](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/ads/display/3035).

Comment: How do I reach for the stat page on sites?

Comment: The last sentence of the question: [bio](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/q/3035/8915): "You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/ads/display/3035)." and [chem](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/2696/2175): "You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/ads/display/2696)."